# passing a default argument to a browserify module

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, commonjs, browserify

I'm refactoring a javascript codebase and am implementing, but I'm new to node. I might run into some code like this:

**foo.js**

```
var foo = {};
foo.bar = function(baz) {
    $('body').append(baz)
}
```

which i would then refactor into the following:

**foo.js**

```
var $ = require('jquery')(window);
var foo = {};
foo.bar = require('./bar');
```

**bar.js**

```
module.exports = bar = function(baz) {
    $('body').append(baz);
}
```

What's the correct way to pass the jQuery object from foo.js to bar.js without interfering with the baz parameter when foo.bar(baz) is called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `var $ = require('jquery')(window)` to each module that needs jQuery!

Calls to `require` that resolve to the same path will return a cached copy of the module:

http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching