# Using NPM jQuery plugin via Browserify without browser field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

Why should I always use "browser" field in package.json to load jQuery plugin installed as npm module?

Some more details:

I'm using browserify-shim to load jQuery via CDN, and want to use jQuery plugin installed as npm module.

My app.js is as the following:

```
var $ = require('jquery'),
    plugin = require('jquery-plugin');

$(function(){
  // test jQuery
  $('.test-jquery').text('jQuery works');

  // test jQuery plugin
  $('.test-plugin').plugin({
    // some config
  });
});
```

My package.json includes the following config for browserify:

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "browserify-shim"
  ]
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "jquery": "global:$"
},
"browser": {
  "jquery-plugin": "./node_modules/jquery-plugin/jquery-plugin.min.js"
}
```

It only works if I have the "browser" field for every plugin I want to use, otherwise I get "plugin is not a function" error at plugin function,  but jQuery works.

How can I skip the "browser" field?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you need the `browserify-shim` at all. Taking jQuery from npm is (should be) commonJS compatible.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst, this way the bundle file becomes too huge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing a default argument to a browserify module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376969/passing-a-default-argument-to-a-browserify-module)